# Changing continue reading in wordpress post page

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

in wordpress twentyeleven theme post page I have used `<!--more-->` for Read more it is showing Continue Reading. I tried alot to change the text to read more but nothing good happened. I changed the string in function.php. But it not worked for me. Here is  the code

[Default]

```
function twentyeleven_continue_reading_link() {
    return ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</a>';
}
```

[Modified]

```
function twentyeleven_continue_reading_link() {
    return ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . __( 'Read More <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</a>';
}
```

Anyhelp and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Have you read this page? [Customizing the Read More](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

Comment: Yes I have but still I am not getting any good result from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, find where your loop gets built. For the main WordPress blog home page, it's the content.php file: (for the TwentyEleven Theme)

Find this line:

`<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>`

Replace it with

`<?php the_content( __( 'Read More <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>`